# How do I split a matrix with different column sizes?

Tags: r, matrix

```
n <- c(12,24)
mu<-c(6.573,6.5)
sigma<-sqrt(0.25)
Diseased.Data<-round(rnorm(n[1], mu[1], sigma), 4)
Healthy.Data<-round(rnorm(n[2], mu[2], sigma), 4)
g <- c(2,3,4)
for(i in 1:3){
  pool.dis.data <- matrix(NA,n[1]/g[i],n[1]/g[i])
 for(j in n[1]/g[i]){
   pool.dis.data <- replicate(n[1]/g[i],mean(sample(Diseased.Data,g[i])))
 }
}
```

When I run the code above, I get only the answer from the last element of g. What I need is each column in the matrix to have an element from `g`. For example, the matrix should look like:

```
m <- cbind(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6)
m1 <- cbind(b1,b2,b3,b4) 
m2 <- cbind(c1,c2,c3)
```

Comment: You keep overwriting `pool.dis.data` in the second loop to a vector. So, you are eventually just left with a vector. Perhaps, you can provide the expected output as a matrix? Your last sentence is not helpful to me as I don't know what a1, a2, ...., b1, b2.....c1, c2... are.

Comment: How can I get a matrix that has varying sizes using the 1st loop?

Comment: I think I figured it out, I used the assign command.